How to filter Product categories by ACF field via WooCommerce REST API
I use WordPress, with WooCommerce and ACF.
For the category, I created a property show_on_main_page (type true/false).
Now I want to get all categories that have show_on_main_page = true
I think the request should look something like this, but it doesn't work
.../wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?meta_key=show_on_main_page&meta_value=true

